# Unable to start the daemon process after adding new directory folder

Tags: android

I add new directory folder and imported a library into my android studio but the gradle sync failed afterwards and I'm getting this error. 
 anyone knows about this ?

Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
OpenJDK Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: do onething go to file-->Invalidate cashe/Restart.